# How to maintain an unpopulated 'config' source file in git repo?

Tags: git

Suppose I create some widget, and decide to share it with Github. In this widget project, there's some configuration/preferences file. I need to share what the values being set are, so that if anyone else wished their own widget they'd know what to set. But I don't necessarily want or need to share my own settings.

This would be a case in which some/all of the settings have no concept of a 'default' - they all need to be explicitly set by the programmer.

I thought I was going to find an answer [in this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163506/how-does-one-handle-sensitive-data-when-using-github-and-heroku), but really that (or at least it's answers) are more focussed on keeping things secret. I don't need to share in confidence - I just don't need to share.

---

#### In essence, I need to deploy `Foo := 'Bar'`, but commit/push/share `Foo :=`.

What's the best way of handling this in Git?

Some possible solutions:

1. Commit the unpopulated file; don't include in later commits with preferences set. Disadvantage: if I add a new setting later, need to remove all values to commit it, and then set them again.
2. Set the values by import/inclusion (as applicable for the language) to ensure an upfront (and less confusing than it might otherwise be) error; clearly state requirements in a readme. Disadvantage: noone likes errors.
3. Branches? I've never really had the need to use multiple, but I have a *feeling* the 'right' way to do this *might* be an un-pushed 'deploy' branch with the values set, and unset in the pushed 'master' branch; just deal with the merge conflicts as they arise on adding new properties? Maybe? Same disadvantage as (1) really, but maybe it's the better practice?

Comment: Why do you think there no acceptable default values? I can't really think of  anything that can't have a "dummy" value e.g. 127.0.0.1 for an IP address or fakedomain.com for a domain name.

Comment: @DaveNay Okay, dummy values, sure. But I suppose then my situation is even slightly worse - I need to commit *different* values, to those I deploy. I guess I was wrong to focus on needing "no value" -- my issue really is "deploy different to what I share". e.g. If I deploy `name := 'Ollie'`, I would commit something like `name := 'Your name here'`.

Comment: Downvote reason?

Answer (score 4):

I would go with a modified version of scenario 1. Instead of adding your *real* configuration file to the repo, add a prototype config file. When the widget first runs, it detects if the config file is present or not. If not present, it renames the prototype file and then loads it. The prototype file can have sane default values (might no "work" but don't crash the widget).

This will allow you to have your local config file (which is never committed, but should probably be backed up) as well as a version that can be publicly pushed that doesn't contain your private information.

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution. Still two files to edit on any change, but I suppose that's unavoidable really since they'd almost certainly conflict every time.

Answer (score 3):

So the idea is: If I check out your git repository, I get a config file template, where I need to fill in the proper values, and you cannot know what the correct values would be for me. In that case, your config file should obviously have plenty of documentation, and building / running the project should fail as early as possible for me if I don't make the necessary changes. It should also be hard for me to commit my fixed config file so it doesn't get distributed by accident (for the same reason that you don't commit your actual config file).

I'd check in a template file, make sure that the whole project is set up so that the template file doesn't become part of the build, and add instructions for me how to create the correct config file, and setup your project so that the correct config file is needed to build. You can else setup git so that it will ignore the config file.

Comment: Oh nice, thanks! That makes things clearer actually. So I could commit the .gitignore with the config file to ensure others don't accidentally commit it -- and this also sets an expected name, which I can then look for, if it doesn't exist, error with "no config file, see template" or similar.

Comment: There's still an issue with detecting/merging when fields are added - but the more I think about it the more I realise that's really just a disadvantage of using a source file as opposed to db.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is: Don't store the populated config file in git at all. Put the unpopulated file in git and on installation or first run, create the populated file in another place. If the configuration is user specific, this other place would be in:

- Windows: %APPDATA%
- Linux: a dot file or a dot folder in the user's home directory. Something like `~/.myapp_config`
- Mac OS X: the user's Library folder, probably in a subdirectory for your app.